# how to authenticate to oracle cloud ipnetwork API using auth token?

Tags: node.js, oracle, authentication, token, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am unable to authenticate to oracle cloud using auth token.I am using "request" node module in node js to connect to oracle cloud using its REST endpoint.I am passing the authentication token in header and the response i am getting is"HTTP 401 Unauthorised".Dont know why it is happening.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which endpoint are you hitting on? Can you show us some code? Have you already read this? http://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/database-dbaas-cloud/csdbr/security-authentication-authorization.html

Comment: hi Dan                                                                                                 REST  endpoint are available in oracle cloud my services option.The code i am using is- request({"method:"POST""RESTendpoint/Compute-identitydomain/network/v1/ipnetwork,body:{"name":{name of the ipnetwork}},headers:{"Cookie":token,content-type}},{callback function})..

Comment: Have you seen this? http://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/iaas/compute-iaas-cloud/stcsa/SendRequests.html Note that the URLs have parts that you must replace with your info, including the identity domain. Please show me the complete URL you're trying to hit on, starting with "https://" (just replace your real identity domain with a fake one).

Comment: yes.I have checked that link as well..the url i am hitting is https://api-z999.compute.us0.oraclecloud.com/network/v1/ipnetwork...As u can see i am using request npm(Node js) ,the body and the header data is getting appended to this url......Note-The REST endpoint is fake.I am appending the identity domain in the "name" key of the body..Its something like  /Compute-{identity domain}/{username}/{ip network name}.

Comment: Okay, the endpoint is wrong. Log into your cloud account. Navigate to the Compute Console and look in the upper-right for the "Site" drop-down. Click that and you should get a popup that gives you the correct endpoint.

Comment: I know about that  we can find  end point from site drop-down in compute console.I am using the very same endpoint in my task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that first obtains a token and then uses it for a subsequent request.

Start by setting these environment variables:

- OC_REST_ENDPOINT
- OC_IDENTITY_DOMAIN
- OC_USER
- OC_PASSWORD

For example:

```
export OC_REST_ENDPOINT=https://api-z999.compute.us0.oraclecloud.com/
export OC_IDENTITY_DOMAIN=myIdentityDomain
export OC_USER=some.user
export OC_PASSWORD=supersecretpassword
```

Then use the following example:

```
const request = require('request');
const restEndpoint = process.env.OC_REST_ENDPOINT;
const identityDomain = process.env.OC_IDENTITY_DOMAIN;
const user = process.env.OC_USER;
const password = process.env.OC_PASSWORD;

request(
  {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: restEndpoint + 'authenticate/',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/oracle-compute-v3+json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ // Must be a string, buffer or read stream
      user: '/Compute-' + identityDomain + '/' + user,
      password: password
    })
  },
  function(err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }

    if (res.statusCode !== 204) {
      console.log('Something broke.');
      return;
    }

    console.log('Got auth token');

    let token = res.headers['set-cookie'][0];

    request(
      {
        method: 'GET',
        uri: restEndpoint + 'instance/',
        headers: {
          'accept': 'application/oracle-compute-v3+directory+json',
          'cookie': token
        }
      },
      function(err, res, body) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
        }

        console.log(body);
      }
    );

  }
);
```